# How can I format result of the SQL in my case?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the table-

```
time
______
     2:00 am
1:05 PM
  12:00  Pm    
 11:10pM
```

Here is what the result should look like-

```
time
______
2:00 am
1:05 PM
12:00 Pm
11:10 pM
```

How can I do it?

If you would like to try-

```
create table tmp (
    time varchar2(50)
);

insert into tmp values ('     2:00 am');
insert into tmp values ('1:05 PM');
insert into tmp values ('  12:00  Pm');
insert into tmp values (' 11:10pM');
```

Comment: TRIM(time), or perhaps LTRIM(time).

Comment: I see there should be space before PM. Can you add information about all anomalies?

Comment: Did any of the below answers help you, OP?

Comment: actually, I solved it myself and have not tested the answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **REGEXP_REPLACE** to modify the data to your desired pattern.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TIME,
  2    regexp_replace(trim(' ' FROM TIME),
  3          '^([[:digit:]]{1,2})(:)([[:digit:]]{1,2})[[:space:]]*([[:alpha:]]{2})$',
  4          '\1\2\3 \4') str
  5  FROM tmp;

TIME            STR
--------------- ----------
     2:00 am    2:00 am
1:05 PM         1:05 PM
  12:00  Pm     12:00 Pm
 11:10pM        11:10 pM
```

The above **REGEXP_REPLACE** query matches the following pattern:

1. `([[:digit:]]{1,2})`
2. `(:)`
3. `([[:digit:]]{1,2})`
4. `([[:alpha:]]{2})`

Each set of parenthesis is a pattern. So, you can see pattern is replaced with `'\1\2\3 \4'`. Which means, pattern 1,2,3 are together followed by a space and ten pattern 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_replace` for formatting complex expressions:

```
select regexp_replace(time, 
  '^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]{1,2}:[[:digit:]]{1,2})[[:space:]]*([aApP][mM]).*$', 
  '\1 \2') from tmp;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba037f/2.

Answer (score 0):

since you have multiple type case of 'pm' i have used case for it.

```
SQL> select * from tmp;

TIME
--------------------------------------------------
     2:00 am
1:05 PM
  12:00  Pm
 11:10pM

SQL> select  (case  substr(time,length(time)-1)
  2  when
  3  'am' then trim(REPLACE(time, 'am',' am'))
  4  when
  5  'PM' then trim(REPLACE(time, 'PM',' PM'))
  6  when
  7  'Pm' then trim(REPLACE(time, ' Pm','Pm'))
  8  when
  9  'pM' then trim(REPLACE(time, 'pM',' pM'))
 10  end) as "time"
 11  from tmp;

time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2:00  am
1:05  PM
12:00 Pm
11:10 pM

SQL>
```

Comment: `12:00   Pm` has two spaces ni between.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by oracle functions but it look like complex query:

```
insert into tmp  values(concat(concat(substr((replace('YourStringDateForInsert',' ','')),0,5),' '),concat(substr((replace('YourStringDateForInsert',' ','')),6,7),' ')));
```